# Windows 10 ISO in Grub2 Multiboot

Tags: boot, windows-10, multi-boot, grub, grub2

I'm attempting to create a multipurpose AIO USB stick for everyday use. So far I've been able to get Mint, Tails, And Hiren's boot cd all successfully working off of one device similar to the tutorial found here:

> http://dann.com.br/grub2-multiboot-usb-linux-mint-tails-and-hirens-boot-cd-luks-encrypted-partition/

However, I'm running into trouble adding Windows 10 to this list. I've done some research but have yet to find a suitable solution for Windows 10.

Is there anyway to add a menuentry to the grub.cfg in order to make this work, or is there a more detailed solution.

Thanks for any help in advance.

EDIT:

I've managed to get the iso to boot using the following menu entry:

```
set root=(hd0,msdos5) #this may be different based on which partition the iso files are currently on
insmod ntldr
ntldr /bootmgr
```

The only problem is once I choose install the following error occurs:

```
A media driver your computer needs is missing. This could be a DVD, USB 
or Hard disk driver. If you have a CD, DVD, or USB flash drive with the driver on it, 
please insert it now.
```

So somehow it can't properly read the files after it starts the setup process.

EDIT 2:

I was able to get the entire thing working with YUMI.

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

Comment: So you are trying to get a fully working Windows 10 working, or just the Windows 10 install?

Comment: Just the Windows 10 install, a persistent OS is an idea, but not necessary right now.

Comment: What is the format for the USB stick? Most Windows install disks only like NTFS.

Comment: I have two partitions, the primary/boot partition is Fat32, that is where my Grub install is located, the second partition is NTFS, that is where the windows ISO files have been extracted. My current theory is that the windows install isn't properly picking up the second NTFS partition after the install starts.